# Disable Access To Acitivites per Profile

Tags: tasks, activities, user-management

Is there a way to restrict access on Task/Activities records per profile? I have created a profile that has access only on Accounts. Nothing else. I want it to be very restricted. But on global search he can search for Tasks and Tasks records are available for view. I suppose this flag is responsible, but i cannot disable it.
[image]
Any ideas ?

Comment: Are you in a professional edition https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000U048QAC

Comment: No, enterprise.